# LibGDX Scene2d: Change width of Table child after it was added

Tags: libgdx, resize, scene2d, scrollpane

I am trying to dynamically change the width of a Scrollpane so its width matches the size of its child element. The Scrollpane is within a Window. The problem is that I don't know the width of the child until after the ScrollPane is added to the Window and `.width()` is already called.

Is there a way to change the ScrollPane's width after it has been added?

P.S. `scrollPane.setWidth()` does not work.

Comment: window.getCell(scrollPane).width(...)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't know how I didn't think of that :) Thank you. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.